# How to get `layoutInflator` in adapter class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a use case...

I want to get `layoutInflator` to bind different Views for nested recyclerView. Is there any best way to get `layoutInflator`?

I was trying to get it from `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder. //something?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be inflating anything in `onBindViewHolder` - `onCreateViewHolder` is where you set up a `ViewHolder` object that displays a list item, including inflating its layout views. `onBindViewHolder` is where you interact with those views, to display the appropriate data for the current item.

Those created `ViewHolder`s get reused, so instead of inflating views for every item, you just create a handful of `ViewHolder`s that get swapped around as you scroll the list. That recycling of a pool of VHs is why it's called a `RecyclerView`.

Generally, you'd store references to the inflated views inside each `ViewHolder`, like in [this example](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter):

```
/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
 * (custom ViewHolder)
 */
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val textView: TextView

    init {
        // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }
}
```

That way, the `ViewHolder` that gets passed into `onBindViewHolder` has a `textView` field you can access, e.g. to set its text contents to display data for the current item. (If you're using View Binding, you could store a reference to the binding object instead, and access the views through `holder.binding.textView` etc)

I don't know what you're doing with nested `RecyclerView`s, but the principle is the same - each `ViewHolder` in the main RV will contain another RV, with its own adapter and data set, created and initialised in `onCreateViewHolder`. If you want to change its contents (because you're displaying a particular item in the main RV list) you'd probably want to add a `setData` function on the nested RV's adapter that changes its data set and refreshes the display. Let the adapter handle inflating things when it needs to, inside `onCreateViewHolder`